# Shell.Application - write new Values?

Tags: powershell, id3

I have a directory with MP3 files. I can read the properties with this script. How I can write properties (Album, Genre, etc.)?

```psh
$com = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('C:\Users\Peter\Music')
for( $index = 0; ((-not $bitrateAttribute) -or (-not $albumAttribute)); ++$index ) {
  $name = $com.GetDetailsOf($com.Items,$index)
  if ($name -eq 'Album') {$albumAttribute = $index}
  if ($name -eq 'Bit rate') {$bitrateAttribute = $index}
}

$com.Items() | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
    Name = $_.Name
    Album = $com.GetDetailsOf($_,$albumAttribute)
    BitRate = $com.GetDetailsOf($_,$bitrateAttribute)
  } | Select-Object -Property Name,Album,BitRate
}
```

Or is there a better way to write ID3 tags to MP3 files?

Comment: Yes there's a better way: use one of the many ID3 tag editors which are specifically made for this.

Comment: Or just use an existing library like Taglib for this job. Google has many results for Powershell and Taglib.

Comment: @Swonkie I prefere to use powershell - if there is a solution

Comment: @peterCo  Yes - i found many Information about Taglib. But is this the only way?

Comment: @ral9004: It is not the only way. But the Taglib library is the most used one. If you are looking for working examples, you should use this. Sorry to say that I can't help you with a plain PowerShell solution.

Comment: @PeterCo  Thank you for this Information. The solution with taglib works well